# Installing Anbox on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, apt, kernel, gnome-terminal, anbox

I use Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot. I have tried all the possible suggestions on installing Anbox, but none have availed to anything. Anbox just opens, shows it is starting, and then closes on its own. I have tried every trick I can find, but none is working. I can't also load the kernel modules no matter what I try, it just fails.
Is there any way to install Anbox?

Comment: `I have tried all the possible suggestions ` - What all did you try?

Comment: https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1610

Comment: https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html

Comment: https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_apps.html

Comment: https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_apps.html

Comment: https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_kernel_modules.html

Comment: I could go on and on but none works. Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the requested details. Thank you for sharing the guide you are following, but these links are not enough to understand the problem you are facing. We need to know the commands you are running and we also need to know the output of commands that did not complete successfully.

Comment: anbox session-manager
[ 2022-04-02 06:43:46] [session_manager.cpp:133@operator()] Failed to start as either binder or ashmem kernel drivers are not loaded

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
[sudo] password for owu6u: 
 
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~morphis/+archive/ubuntu/anbox-support
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:2 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:3 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]

Comment: Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:6 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Reading package lists... Done                                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: sudo apt install linux-headers-generic anbox-modules-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package anbox-modules-dkms

Comment: he repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.